# Oracle OBIEE Analytics 12c date validation

Tags: validation, analytics, oracle12c, business-intelligence, obiee

In **OBIEE12c**, I have multiple reports wherein the user input is 2 dates i.e From Date and To Date.

For all these reports, the requirement is on click of **'Apply'** button, a common js should get called where in

1. I have to retrieve the report name that is invoked so that only for those reports these date validates can be applied.
2. I have to retrieve the From date selected by the user
3. I have to retrieve the To date selected by the user
4. Have to add the validation which compares the From Date < To Date and find out the difference between dates and provide an alert to the user informing him that the date difference is more than 90 days

My ultimate requirement explained in single line would be `show an alert (after date comparison) to the user for couple of reports on click of Apply in OBIEE 12c`

**If there is any other way to achieve it please highlight!**

We had achieved the above requirement in OBIEE10g, but the same is not working post migration/upgrade to 12c ( 10g to 11g and 11g to 12c Two Step Process

Answer (score 1):

I would use standard BI functionality rather than invoking javascript.

If the requirement is to ensure reports are not run for more than 90 days I would just use standard dashboard prompts for start and end date and then in my analyses add a filter with the expression

```
case when TimestampDiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, "Table"."Start Date", "Table"."End Date" > 90 then 0 else 1 end
```

and make it equal 1.   This will ensure the report doesn't return data.

Then I would create an analysis with the same filter than just returns a row or not.   This analysis can then be used as a condition on a sections.   You can put some static text in a section that only displays when the condition returns no rows telling users that their selection needs to be less than 90 days.   You can choose whether or not to display the analysis based on the inverse condition on the section containing it.

Comment: Nice one! Seeing attempts to muddle the solution with JS is definitely cringe-worthy and a clear sign that the approach chosen is just wrong.